# Gradle update in IntelliJ destroyed external lib DSL

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, corda

I’m a gradle newb - was running the corda template M13 fine in intelliJ, until an intelliJ prompt asked if I wanted to update gradle.

After carelessly clicking ‘yes’, all Corda DSL now has unresolved references. What is the shortest path to retract|update rest of project?

If possible an explanation would be appreciated too. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible your `/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties` has been corrupted - particularly after a refactoring involving "services". Check that the `distributionUrl` reads as follows:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-bin.zip
```